# how do I convert Sensor data to degrees

Tags: android, geometry, android-sensors

I am getting various sensor readings from my device (programing for android)  and i am looking to get the roll (which seems to be a number 1-100) converted into an angle in degrees and also convert the magnetometer heading into degrees..

any simple equations would be appreciated.. my geometry is a fleeting memory..

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            int type=evt.sensor.getType();
            if(type == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION){
                azimuth = evt.values[0]; // azimuth rotation around the z-axis
                pitch = evt.values[1];   // pitch rotation around the x-axis
                roll = evt.values[2];    // roll rotation around the y-axis
            }

            //Smoothing the sensor data a bit seems like a good idea.
            if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                orientation[0]=(orientation[0]*1+evt.values[0])*0.5f;
                orientation[1]=(orientation[1]*1+evt.values[1])*0.5f;
                orientation[2]=(orientation[2]*1+evt.values[2])*0.5f;
            } else if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                acceleration[0]=(acceleration[0]*2+evt.values[0])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[1]=(acceleration[1]*2+evt.values[1])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[2]=(acceleration[2]*2+evt.values[2])*0.33334f;
            }
            if ((type==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) || (type==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
                float newMat[]=new float[16];
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "accel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(newMat, null, acceleration, orientation);
                if(displayOri==0||displayOri==2){
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newMat,SensorManager.AXIS_X*-1, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y*-1,newMat);
                }else{
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newMat,SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,newMat);
                }
                matrix=newMat;
            }
        }
```

I should add that i am not sure i just want roll.. my app locks in landscape mode but obviously the user can turn their phone to any angle on any access..  so i probably need all three of the above to get the angle im looking for.

the angle in question is as if the user is looking through their phone, no matter how they are holding it, at the real world and i want the angle they are looking off the horizon..

for instance if they are looking at the horizon i want 90degrees returned, if they are looking straight up in the sky i should get 180, straight down -180.. then i will also want the degrees from magnetic north that they are looking.. using the magnetometer

Comment: Have you looked at the example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

`values[2]` should allready contain degree-value, that's mentioned in a [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html#onSensorChanged%28int,%20float%5B%5D%29):

> values[2]: Roll, rotation around Y axis (-90<=roll<=90), with positive
>   values when the z-axis moves toward the x-axis.

**Update**

Take a look at this picture: http://developer.android.com/images/axis_device.png

Here you see blue axis - Y axis. When your phone turns around it, it's called "rolling". The angle of the rotation will be contained in `values[2]`.

Comment: well for roll i am using the orientation sensor and getting a value between 0 and 100 essentially, i tried using Math.toDegrees() but got numbers up to about 5500 which cant be right.. where you have "percent" is that the natural roll?  i am editing my post to include the code i am using to get roll ect..

Comment: 'Math.toDegrees(double angrad)' converts from radians to degrees not from "1-100" to degrees :) I'm waiting for more details.

Comment: "values[2]: Roll, rotation around Y axis (-90<=roll<=90), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the x-axis.

Note that this definition of yaw, pitch and roll is different from the traditional definition used in aviation where the X axis is along the long side of the plane (tail to nose)."  does this mean that it already uses [0] and [1] to make ajustments?  and how come i am getting a number between -10 and 10 essentialy

Comment: Dude, I don't understand what do you need :) What numbers are you talking about? Firstly you wrote about some "1-100" values, now you want to get something in "-10..10" range... 

See the update please.

Comment: my app is set to lanscape, i want the angle in degrees, of the y axis but the user can also hold their phone in portrait mode and in that case i want the angle of the y axis.  its not giving me degrees its giving me int. roll = evt.values[2]; gives me int